# How Spring+JPA integration actually works

Tags: java, spring, jpa

A simple banking application:
[image]

Points to note:

- Implemented using Spring+JPA with EclipseLink as JPA provider
- EntityManager is injected into BaseDaoImpl using @PersistenceContext
- DAOs are autowired into the Service bean
- @Transactional annotation used at service methods

Questions:

1. Does each DAO get its own instance of EntityManager or is the instance shared?
2. If they are separate instances, how do transactions work?
3. If shared instance, when is the connection closed? At application shutdown? Does it mean, there is only one connection for the entire application, irrespective of number of DAO/entities and it remains open for the application lifetime?

Answer (score 3):

An instance of `EntityManager` injected using `@PersistenceContext` is a proxy that delegates actual work to `EntityManager` associated with the current transaction.

In other words, it works as follows:

- When you enter `@Transactional` scope, new transaction is created and associated with the current thread
- When you call a method of `EntityManager` in your DAO, the call is delegated to `EntityManager` associated with the current transaction (new `EntityManager` will be created if doesn't exist)
- When you leave `@Transactional` scope, transaction gets committed and `EntityManager` associated with it gets closed

Answer (score 1):

What's get injected into the DAO using `@PersistenceContext` is actually not the Entity Manager implementation of the underlying ORM but Spring proxy which will delegate the calls to the 
actual underlying entity manager. The concrete class for the proxy is usually `SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler`.

The scope of the underlying Entity Manager is usually the scope of Spring managed transaction ( the other is extended scope which is out of question here)
The Spring transaction manager ( typically JpaTransactionManager when JPA is used as data access) binds the EntityManager to the current thread and the entity manager is subsequently retrieved from here untill the transaction commits. For a new transaction again the same thing happens.
You can take a look at source code of [JpaTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.java) `doBegin` method where this all happens.